# JasperReports XLS export pagination and other issues

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm having trouble with JasperReports 4.0.2 XLS export. The file comes out but it seems to have certain issues each time, no matter which configuration I try:

- Column headers will disappear unless I disable graphics e.g. vertical line separating the headers and the data.
- I cannot remove repeating page and column headers and have all the data as a single details block. The page numbers cannot be removed also.

The same template is used for PDF export (which should have pages) and XLS export (which should be without pages). For achieving the desired XLS export I've tried configuring the export with JRXlsExporter parameters in the java code as well as changing properties in the default.jasperreports.properties file.

This far I haven't found any actual documentation on the topic. Few forums posts in the JasperReports site seem not to be working.

### The Problem is solved.

Somehow JasperReports ignored the properties set in the java code during the export process with JRXlsExporter class and the properties file. However, the same delcarations did work then added directly to the JRXML file. The working code to remove repeating headers is below:

```
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.2" value="columnHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
```

The titles did disappear due to separator line being drawn on top of the titles themself. PDF could handle this but XLS did not. By adding a few pixels of space in between the titles and the separator the problem did solve.

Comment: The issue with disappearing elements with XLS (and also HTML) exporters is that these exporters aren't able to deal with overlapping elements. So if a line is drawn anywhere within the space of a text field, then one of the two won't be visible in XLS (or HTML) reports. The PDF exporter is however able to deal with this.